# D3.js time format

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I need some help parsing datetime string with locale info `2014-03-12T15:47:17.000+0000` in d3, I tried this `var iso = d3.time.format.utc("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%LZ+0000")` but didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a leading % on the Z which *seems* to have worked.  This is different to the example in the documentation, so if you're convinced that the documentation isn't correct then open an issue.  Before doing that I'd check which version of d3 you're using.

Back to the question at hand, I set the formatter like this:

```
formater = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%L%Z")
```

and tested it by passing your string to the formatter like this:

```
formater.parse("string")
```

Which resulted in:

`Thu Mar 13 2014 02:47:17 GMT+1100 (AUS Eastern Summer Time)`

Answer (score 1):

```
d3.time.format.utc("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%L%Z")
  .parse('2014-03-12T15:47:17.000+0000')

// Wed Mar 12 2014 11:47:17 GMT-0400 (EDT)
```

Note that (at least on my version of Chrome) this works too:

```
new Date('2014-03-12T15:47:17.900+0000')

// Wed Mar 12 2014 11:47:17 GMT-0400 (EDT)
```

But I don't know that it works in all browsers.